# Use tensorflow optimizer.apply_gradients when you want to add learning_rate * gradient to current values

Tags: tensorflow

Since I have a maximization problem, I need to do gradient ascent rather than gradient descent (for some reason converting maximization problem to minimization problem by multiplying cost function by -1 is not possible).

I am wondering how I can do that. Can I use negative value for learning rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried using a negative learning rate for `optimizer.apply_gradients()`, so wouldn't know if it works. However, one way to have negative gradients is by using:

```
    negative_gradient = list(map(lambda x: tf.multiply(x, -1), gradient))
```

Also, I guess you obtain `gradient` via `tf.gradients(loss, params)` or `optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, params)`. You could just use `-loss`in this case.